# install in nfs shared directory

Tags: nfs, share, installation

I have a NFS Ubuntu server and have shared /opt directory among all clients. I want to install packages in /opt directory so that I dont have to install it in all clients. So what I did was download the .deb file and tried using the command

> dpkg --root=/opt -i pkg.deb

And I get the following error.

> dpkg: error: unable to access dpkg status area: No such file or directory

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You fix this by not doing this. Harddisk space is cheap, don't complicate your life by trying to save a few bytes with an NFS setup.

Also, even if you made this work by creating /opt/var/lib/dpkg etc, the applications still would not work, as they think they're installed in the normal location. The --root option is for installing things into complete debian chroots.